# jQuery / Regex: remove Div with nested Divs from TD

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a TD that always contains a div and some text outside the div.

The div has four nested divs that always follow the below structure. 
The only thing I am interested in is the text in this TD that appears outside the main div, everything else should be removed.

The text I want to keep varies, the structure of the rest is fixed.

**Example TD:**

```
<td id="myTD">
    <div id="show_status_1622327228" class="nor_addr_status" onmouseout="show_status_div(2, this);" onmouseover="show_status_div(1, this);" style="display: none;">
        <div id="status_safe_1622327228" class="status_hov" onmouseout="javascript:chgcolor(2, this);" onmouseover="javascript:chgcolor(1, this);">
            Text1
        </div>
        <div id="status_unknown_1622327228" class="status_hov" onmouseout="javascript:chgcolor(2, this);" onmouseover="javascript:chgcolor(1, this);">
            Text2
        </div>
        <div id="status_pr_1622327228" class="status_hov" onmouseout="javascript:chgcolor(2, this);" onmouseover="javascript:chgcolor(1, this);" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
            Text3
        </div>
        <div id="status_fraud_1622327228" class="status_hov" onmouseout="javascript:chgcolor(2, this);" onmouseover="javascript:chgcolor(1, this);" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
            Text4
        </div>
    </div>
    The only text I want to keep
</td>
```

**I tried the following but this doesn't work - probably because of the nested divs:**

```
$('#myTD').text().replace(/<div[\s\S]+?<\/div>/g, "").replace(/<a[\s\S]+?<\/a>/g, ""));
```

My problem here is that it keeps the texts from the nested divs (Text1, Text2, Text3, Text4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$("#myTD>div").remove()
```

Answer (score 3):

Ten kittens in China just died, and four unicorns where brutally sterilized!
Why would you do such a thing with a regex ?

To remove *every DOM node* and just keep textNodes, filter on nodeType and remove the rest.

```
$('#myTD').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType != 3;
}).remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/q454k/)

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as -

```
$('#myTD').find('div').remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/remove/