# jQuery: use .remove() instead of Regex inside object

Tags: jquery, regex, removechild

I have a TD that always contains a div and some text outside the div.

The div has four nested divs that always follow the below structure. 
The only thing I am interested in is the text in this TD that appears **outside** the main div, everything else should be removed.

The text I want to keep varies, the structure of the rest is fixed.

**Example TD:**

```
<td>
    <div id="show_status_1622327228" class="nor_addr_status" onmouseout="show_status_div(2, this);" onmouseover="show_status_div(1, this);" style="display: none;">
        <div id="status_safe_1622327228" class="status_hov" onmouseout="javascript:chgcolor(2, this);" onmouseover="javascript:chgcolor(1, this);">
            Text1
        </div>
        <div id="status_unknown_1622327228" class="status_hov" onmouseout="javascript:chgcolor(2, this);" onmouseover="javascript:chgcolor(1, this);">
            Text2
        </div>
        <div id="status_pr_1622327228" class="status_hov" onmouseout="javascript:chgcolor(2, this);" onmouseover="javascript:chgcolor(1, this);" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
            Text3
        </div>
        <div id="status_fraud_1622327228" class="status_hov" onmouseout="javascript:chgcolor(2, this);" onmouseover="javascript:chgcolor(1, this);" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
            Text4
        </div>
    </div>
    The only text I want to keep
</td>
```

I tried the following which works fine. My only concern is the multiple replaces / Regexes and I am wondering if I could use .remove() instead in order to reduce loading times.

If this is possible, can someone here tell me how I have to adjust it ?
Note: The first line of the below needs to remain unchanged, this is only about the replace / Regex part below.

```
util.setProp(obj, "address", $(msg).find("#tab_address_info")
    .find("td:contains('(Home)')").prev().text()
    .replace(/<div[\s\S]+?<\/div>/g, '')
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery / Regex: remove Div with nested Divs from TD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119900/jquery-regex-remove-div-with-nested-divs-from-td)

Comment: This is not the same as here I am using an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Milind Anantwar said you can use `.remove()`.  If you want to get the value of the text outside the divs to set somewhere else but not actually remove the divs from the page then you will need to `.clone()`before you `.remove()`

I think maybe you want something like

```
var td = $('td.cleantd').clone(); //Using comment above - otherwise find the right td yourself
$('div', td).remove();
util.setProp(obj, "address", td.text());
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3xZQ/)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 $('td div').remove();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q94Ub/)**

**Update:** by targetting DIV

```
 $('.status_hov').closest('td').find('div').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to know how to apply this to the above. How can I refer to the div when I say "td:contains('(Home)')" as above ?

Comment: Give some class to td and then target the DOM. lets say you give `class="cleantd"` . then use `$('td.cleantd div').remove();`

Comment: Unfortunately I cant give a class to the TD as this is an internal website that I cannot modify. Finding my TD like above works, I just need to put in the reference to the div.

Comment: @user2571510: How about this- `$('.status_hov').closest('td').find('div').remove();`

Comment: Thanks for this. What is .status_hov ?